# mongodb: pull one item from nested array of references

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nested array of references

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
   posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
  }
);
```

from that array I want to remove one reference, I assumed this would be easy using

```
 User.update({ name: currentName}, { $pull: { posts: postId }});
```

this and variations like

```
 User.update(
    { name: currentName},
    { $pull: { posts: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId) } }
  );
```

or using `findOneAndUpdate` all didn't work for me.

`postId` is formated like for example `"5c150b855999681f7423aacb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('YOUR_DATA_ID')
},
{ name: currentName,
{ $pull: { posts: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId) } }
);
```

Comment: why did you put the `id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('YOUR_DATA_ID')` there? It worked without it for me.

Comment: name is not an unique one. if you use findOneAndUpdate, need to find an unique value in records.So I use to findOne with _id and Update the records